# Difference between sharepoint subsite SPWeb.AllUsers and SPWeb.SiteUsers?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Based on MS:

**SPWeb.AllUsers
Gets the collection of user objects that represents all users who are either members of the site or who have browsed to the site as authenticated members of a domain group in the site.**

Note the word "**browsed to**"

**SPWeb.SiteUsers
Gets the collection of all users that belong to the site collection.**

My question is: Does this mean SiteUsers is the combination of AllUsers for all the subsites in the site collection? Which means, only includes **who have browsed to the site as authenticated members of a domain group in the site**? or, it includes users who have not browsed yet?

If I want to get all users, **including members of the site AND who have the permission to browse the site as authenticated members of a domain group in the site**, how to do it? Does it mean we will have to get all groups in the AD, then check whether the group have the permission for the site?

Thanks

Comment: And why is this tagged powershell?

Comment: I use SP Powershell for this, and I thought it is related with powershell. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 5):

Check this link [users-vs-allusers-vs-siteusers](http://snahta.blogspot.ca/2008/12/users-vs-allusers-vs-siteusers.html)

SiteUsers > AllUsers > Users

Users => explicitly provide a user permission to the site 
AllUsers => Users that have accessed the site via some group membership + Users 
SiteUsers => AllUsers for all subsites + site collection admins

Comment: AllUsers => Users can get access to site via some group membership + Users . This is not correct. It is Users who have accessed the site via group membership + Users. If the user has permission, but never accessed the site, it is not included in AllUsers.